# c++ longest interval's first and last element where elements are bigger than 0

Tags: c++, intervals

I have an array called `days[m]` which contains `m` numbers.

I am trying to get the longest interval's first and last elements index where every `int` between those 2 indexes is bigger than 0.

Example:

Input:

> days[m] = {1,2,2,3,3,5}

Output:

> 1 3

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
int max = 0,ind,ind2,db;

for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
    if(days[i] > 0){
        db = 1;
        int j = i;

        while(days[j] > 0){
            db++;
            j++;
        }
        
        if(db > max){
            max = db;
            ind = i;
            ind2 = i+db;
        }
    }
}
cout<<ind<<" "<<ind2<<endl;
```

Comment: 3 doesn't appear to be the correct end index of the interval that you're looking for.

Comment: @cigien i know i tried bad 1 and 3 have to be the ouput cuz 1,2,3 is in the array but 4 isn't and 1,2,3 = 3 and 5 = 1 so its 1 and 3

Comment: Unclear the interval in int range and not index-range...

Comment: So you are not looking for the index, but two numbers a<b such that all integers in [a,b] are in the array?

Comment: I'm even more confused now. That doesn't appear to match the description in the question body. Could you add some more examples of input and output? That might clarify things.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad the first and last element of the interval, not the index

Comment: You might `std::sort` input, then `std::unique` it. then it should be easy to construct "range" and find the biggest one.

Comment: Is your input range already sorted?